# Bad react.js performance with associated data and two-way-binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To familiarize myself with react.js I've wrote a Facebook-like news stream including user comments. I tried make the user names changeable, so I used a two-way-binding between the users object and the feed component. But it isn't very performant and I don't know if it is a react issue or if I have a conceptual problem.

**Problem Case:**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mk1uf8x2/2/) is an simple example on JSFiddle. On top of the page you can change a user name and react updates all names.

I get the data from my own API in a format like this:

```
{
    "feeds": [
        {
            "_id": "feed_1",
            "user": "user_1",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "_id": "comment_1",
                    "user": "user_2",
                    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "user_1",
            "name": "Allan Moreno"
        },
        {
            "_id": "user_2",
            "name": "Edward Mendez"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

So I have an array with feeds and an array with users. I iterate over the feeds to generate the react feed components. The feeds and comments get their users from a *getUserById* function I pass as react property.

```
var StreamContainer = React.createClass({
    getUserById: function(userId) {
        for(var i=0; i<this.state.users.length; i++) {
            if(this.state.users[i]._id === userId) {
                return this.state.users[i];
            }
        }
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            "feeds": [...],
            "users": [...]
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        var getUserById = this.getUserById;

        return (
            <div className="stream-container">
                <FeedList getUserById={getUserById} feeds={this.state.feeds} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var FeedList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var getUserById = this.props.getUserById;

        var feedNodes = this.props.feeds.map(function(feed) {
            return [<Feed key={feed._id} feed={feed} getUserById={getUserById} />];
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <strong>Feeds:</strong>
                <ol className="stream-items">
                    {feedNodes}
                </ol>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Feed = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var getUserById = this.props.getUserById;

        return (
            <li className="stream-item">
                <strong>{getUserById(this.props.feed.user).name}:</strong> <em>{this.props.feed.text}</em>
                <FeedCommentList comments={this.props.feed.comments} getUserById={getUserById} />
            </li>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <StreamContainer />,
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
);
```

Now I've tried to make it a little interactive for some performance tests. I've added a list of all users to change their names dynamically. For the two-way-binding I use [ReactLink](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

```
var StreamContainer = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    ...

    render: function() {
        ...

        var valueLink = this.linkState('users');
        var handleChange = function(e) {
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
        };

        return (
            <div className="stream-container">
                <UserList users={this.state.users} valueLink={valueLink} />
                <FeedList getUserById={getUserById} feeds={this.state.feeds} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var UserList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var valueLink = this.props.valueLink;

        var users = this.props.users.map(function(user, index) {
            var thisValueLink = {};

            var handleChange = function(newValue) {
                valueLink.value[index].name = newValue;
                valueLink.requestChange(valueLink.value);
            };

            thisValueLink.requestChange = handleChange;
            thisValueLink.value = valueLink.value[index].name;

            return [<User key={user._id} user={user} valueLink={thisValueLink} />];
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <strong>Users:</strong>
                <ul>
                    {users}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var User = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>                            
                <input type="text" valueLink={this.props.valueLink} /> {this.props.user.name} 
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

But now I run into a performance problem. If I change the name of a user react has to check all names for updates. So if I have 100 feeds you can see the delay between input and update.

Is there a better way to pass the users to the child components? Or maybe a more performant way to handle two-way-bindings?

Comment: getUserById needing to iterate through every user each time it is called (meaning, rendering all users iterates through every user for each user) is potentially slow. You'd be better off creating an object of user objects that is keyed by user id. Therefor you iterate through every user only once. Then getUserById is simply `return users[id]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good point. I've already tested a version with keyed objects.    
The problem with this is, that I cannot iterate over an object with _this.props.users.map()_.
And if I use _React.Children.map(this.props.users, function(user, index) { ... })_ the object will be flatted like

`users[0] = "user_1";
users[1] = "Allan Moreno";
users[2] = "user_2";
users[3] = "Edward Mendez";
...`

Comment: Have you tried a browser profiler? I'd start there.

Comment: @Johann: I'm not saying your JSON data needs to be an object. Just that the getUserById function should cache a version of the data that is a keyed object (either in a closure or as a private member of StreamContainer)

Comment: @slebetman: Okay, that makes sense. I think that will be a little faster. 

But in my opinion there are still two performance problems with my react.js code:
**#1** All users have to call `getUserById()`. I don't know if there is another possibility to pass the users directly as _props_ to the feeds instead of the `getUserById` function.
**#2** The two-way-binding: on each change react calls `this.setState({users: newUsers})` to update the whole users object. Is there a way to update just one property like `this.setState({users[2].name: newUserName})`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a username dictionary object in the StreamContainer render to pass around to children that need to lookup user names:

```
var userNames = {};
this.state.users.forEach(function(user) {
    userNames[user._id] = user.name;
});

<FeedList usernames={userNames} feeds={this.state.feeds} />
```

then it's just a simple key lookup, eg:

```
var Feed = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li className="stream-item">
                <strong>{this.props.usernames[this.props.feed.user]}:</strong> <em>{this.props.feed.text}</em>
                <FeedCommentList comments={this.props.feed.comments} usernames={this.props.usernames} />
            </li>
        );
    }
});



var FeedCommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var _this = this;
        var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment) {
            return [
                <FeedComment 
                    key={comment._id} 
                    username={_this.props.usernames[comment.user]} 
                    comment={comment} />
            ];
        });

...
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk1uf8x2/3/)

Comment: That looks like an elegant way to handle the keyed user object. I've included this in my news stream but it is still very slow. [This react example](https://jsfiddle.net/mk1uf8x2/4/) has 100 feeds (500 user watchers) and you can see a big input delay. Maybe react.js watchers are not so fast but in AngularJS I can handle 2000 watchers without big delays.